# how to display the total time of the video before it starts running 

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg

I´m using java and ffmpeg.

I need to get the real time of a video, but i can´t do this. I read that this program does it but i still can not implement. If anyone knows of another way?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any specific library to do this, or wrapping ffmpeg yourself manually?

The best approach would be to use one of the wrappers out there already such as Xuggler. VLCj would be another alternative to do this. Both require native libraries underneath, but give you Java APIs to work with making the task much simpler.